# Provide Git credentials to Nebula Gradle plugin on Jenkins using Github App

Tags: git, gradle, jenkins, netflix-nebula-plugins

We have a Jenkins configured to use Github app to perform all Git related activities. A project of ours uses the [Nebula Gradle plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin) for release process. So, whenever the `final` task runs on Jenkins, the first Gradle task that runs is `prepare` which performs a `git fetch` using the internal JGit. In doing so it fails with the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/yyy/zzz.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
```

So, the question is - how do I make the nebula plugin to use the credentials provided by the Github App configured on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your `Jenkinsfile` as follows:

```
steps {
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'github-app-id',
                   usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_APP',
                   passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN')]) {
    sh 'export GRGIT_USER=$GITHUB_APP && export GRGIT_PASS=$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN && ./gradlew final'
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in 18+ versions of `nebula.release` plugin as `grgit` has been [removed](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin/pull/243). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461877/from-nebula-17-to-18-0-4-grgit-stopped-working-in-jenkins-context/77585356#77585356) when using a 18+ version with Jenkins