# From nebula 17 to 18.0.4 GRGIT stopped working in jenkins context

Tags: gradle, jenkins, netflix-nebula-plugins

in gradle nebula plugin 17.2.1 the code below works
using 18.0.4 it does not and fails with `org.gradle.api.GradleException: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

grgit remains in the nebula project's tests but not in the src ([search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anebula-plugins%2Fnebula-release-plugin%20grgit&type=code)).  There are no docs on how to pass git creds from Jenkins layer or OS layer down to the gradle layer.  It looks like the plugin maintainers decided to reduce the scope of their project without adding useful documentation.

Jenkins file code

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credid',
 passwordVariable: 'GRGIT_PASS',
 usernameVariable: 'GRGIT_USER')]) {
   script {
     sh("./gradlew final recordVersion --stacktrace")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With 18.0.4, I was able to get this working in two different ways.

**Option 1: (changes in both Jenkinsfile and build.gradle)**

Add a custom git remote with the github token in Jenkins and then configure the gradle plugin to use that remote instead of the default remote, which is set to `origin`.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credid', 
                                 passwordVariable: 'GRGIT_PASS', 
                                 usernameVariable: 'GRGIT_USER')]) {
    sh '''
        git remote add auth https://$GRGIT_PASS@github.com/someorg/some-repo.git
        ./gradlew final
    '''
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
release {
    remote = 'auth'
}
```

**Option 2: (changes in only Jenkinsfile)**

Add a git config to replace the remote URL with a URL that includes the github token

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credid', 
                                 passwordVariable: 'GRGIT_PASS', 
                                 usernameVariable: 'GRGIT_USER')]) {
    sh '''
        git config url."https://${GRGIT_PASS}@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
        ./gradlew final
    '''
}
```

Comment: ooh thanks.  I'll try that approach when I get back to my ticket and click the check then